# Popoviciu's inequality

Tags: convex-analysis, functional-inequalities, jensen-inequality

If $f(x): \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is a convex function, prove that
$$f(x) + f(y) + f(z) + 3 f(\frac{x + y + z}{3}) \geq 2 f(\frac{x + y}{2}) + 2 f(\frac{x + z}{2}) + 2 f(\frac{y + z}{2})$$

I proved the first case where $\displaystyle y ≤ \frac{x+y+z}{3}$ and I don't know how to prove for the second case where $\displaystyle y ≥ \frac{x+y+z}{3}$

Comment: It seems that you denote $x<y<z$ for $x_1, x_2, x_3$. If my interpretation is correct, then the second case follows from the first case. Indeed you simply have to consider the convex function $f(-x)$. Then $-z<-y<-x$ and $-y \le  \frac{1}{3}[(-x)+(-y)+(-z)]$

Comment: @Crostul Could you please help me in writing the proof for the second case?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you already proved the following:

> Suppose that $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is a convex function, $x\le y \le z$ are real numbers. If $$y \le \frac{x+y+z}{3}$$ then
> $$f(x) + f(y) + f(z) + 3 f(\frac{x + y + z}{3}) \geq 2 f(\frac{x + y}{2}) + 2 f(\frac{x + z}{2}) + 2 f(\frac{y + z}{2})$$

We want to prove the inequality in the case when $y \ge \frac{x+y+z}{3}$.

Let's introduce three new variables
$$x' = -z; \quad y'=-y; \quad z'=-x$$ and a new function $f': \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ defined by
$$f'(t)= f(-t)$$
Since $f$ is convex, $f'$ is convex too (I cannot prove it here, since I don't know which definition of convex function you use). Moreover, under the assumptions $x \le y \le z$ and $y \ge \frac{x+y+z}{3}$ we have $$x' \le y' \le z'; \qquad y' \le \frac{x'+y'+z'}{3}$$
Hence we can use the theorem above with $f', x', y', z'$.

This concludes the proof.

Comment: Thank you so much. How would you prove that  $f'$ is convex too? I can work with either the second derivative of the function or the definition of a convex function.

Comment: As for the second derivative you can simply argue by $$\frac{\mathrm d^2}{\mathrm d t^2} f(-t) =- (- f''(-t)) >0 $$ The function $f(-t)$ has a graph symmetric of the graph of $f$, hence secant segments are above the graph.